# Django form without model not appearing in template when rendered

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a form without an associated model, just a contact form for sending a message.

I have some experience with django forms by now, so I thought I had done everything correctly, but nothing ends up rendering when the page is viewed in a browser at all, nor are there any errors to troubleshoot.

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['full_name', 'phone', 'email', 'message']
        full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        email = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        message = forms.CharField(max_length=400)
```

And my view that turns the form into something useful:

```
def contact_view(request):
    full_name = request.POST.get('full_name', False)
    phone = request.POST.get('phone', False)
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    message = request.POST.get('message', False)
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
#        send_emails(first_name, last_name, email)
        template = loader.get_template('/myapp/mysite/main_page/templates/main_page/thankyoumsg.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))
    template = loader.get_template('/myapp/mysite/main_page/templates/main_page/contact.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))
```

And my template:

```
<form class="leave-comment" action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But nothing is displaying, and I am unsure why. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: The view seem a bit sketchy, as `if form.is_valid():` may very well generate `True` even when no form is posted. What happens if you indent the `if form.is_valid():`-part to be included in the `if request.method == 'POST':` ?

Comment: @Johan that's a good point, thankyou. Indented as you suggested, but nothing changed :\

Comment: If nothing else, try to print any text at all in the templates (for both `thankyoumsg.html` and `contact.html`) and see which page shows up. Also, if you view page source, can you see other form components such as the submit button?

Comment: @johan contact.html shows up fine, I haven't been able to submit the form to test thankyoumsg.html. Viewing the source was the first thing I tried and yeah, the submit button is there as well as the opening form tag, just none of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including the form in the response at the last line. This should (probably) do the trick:

```
def contact_view(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponse(template.render({'form': form}, request))
```

I also believe you need to add the fields directly to the form class, not in the Meta-class.

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Move out the fields here instead
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=400)

    class Meta:
        # This may still be there but may also be a bit redundant since
        # you're choosing to show all applied fields.
        fields = ['full_name', 'phone', 'email', 'message']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this however, and still no change, when viewing the source of the rendered page or in any other behaviour :\

Comment: Ah, it's likely in the view then. Try to add the form to the context with in the `HttpResponse` with this for the last line: `return HttpResponse(template.render({'form': form}, request))`

Comment: That was it! Thank you

Comment: @JakeRankin Cheers no problem!

Answer (score 1):

**class Meta** is only used when you have a **model**. If you only need to render a form without a specific model use it this way. for more information please visit official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=400)
```

views.py

```
 def contact_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

       form = ContactForm(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid():

            full_name = form.cleaned_data['full_name']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            template = loader.get_template('/myapp/mysite/main_page/templates/main_page/thankyoumsg.html')
            return HttpResponse(template.render({'form': form}, request))

        template = loader.get_template('/myapp/mysite/main_page/templates/main_page/thankyoumsg.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render({'form': form}, request))

    form = ContactForm()
    template = loader.get_template('/myapp/mysite/main_page/templates/main_page/contact.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({'form': form}, request))
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize class Meta was only for use when I have a model. Thank you. I was using class Meta to define some attributes using forms.TextInput, now that this does not work, I suppose it is a new question.

Comment: @JakeRankin I updated my answer if its correct mark it as valid so other users can benefit from it.

Comment: Thank you @m1009ct0, I up voted you but selected Johan's answer as best just because he beat you and got me to the working solution first. But thank you very much!

Comment: @m1009ct0 While I usually encourage a variety of answers, it does seem weird when you give the same answer as I (as well in the same order I come up with them) and then ask for marking your answer as the given solution. It's fine if there's a different tweak to the answer, and if you feel my answer could be improved you can also [improve my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55348040/edit). You can read more [here about asking to accept a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88535/404661).